# Using USB 2.0 devices on a USB 3.0 hub

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, usb-3

I currently have a 7-way USB 2.0 hub. However, when any other device on my hub communicates with the PC (especially my external hard drive which is USB3 compatible), the external sound card stutters. Consequently it uses its own USB2 port.

I am getting a new laptop with USB3 ports. If I were to switch to a USB3 hub, would the extra bandwidth prevent this from happening, or would USB2.0 devices still share the 480Mbps between them?

Comment: I'm wondering if the stuttering of the soundcard has anything to do with the power consumption of the hub when the external HDD is plugged in? Does the disk have its own power supply or is it bus powered?

Comment: No;  USB 2.0 devices plugged into USB 3.0 run at USB 2.0 speeds there is zero performance gained by plugging USB 2.0 devices in USB 3.0 hubs.

Comment: The hub has an external power supply but the hard drive does not. That could be what's causing the stuttering. It's not too much of an issue as I only plug in the drive once a week for backup, and that's at 12am on Saturday when I'm usually either out or not on the computer.

Answer (score 0):

You need a 3.0 compactable USB Device to connect it to a 3.0 USB Hub, Then I suppose you can archive the full bandwidth!